# Double Clicking Row on PyQt4 QTableWidget sets the content to -1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I have recently started to use PyQt4 for making GUI applications. I was trying to make an application in which I used the QTableWidget. It's is 2-column table where the first column was set to QLineEdit and second column was set to QListWidget using delegates (sorry if "set to" is not the correct terminology"). The entries in the QListWidget column are coming from the list output of a QFileDialog

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import uic
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

qtCreatorFile = "app_name.ui"  # UI File designed using QtDesigner
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class DelegateLEdit(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        line_edit = QLineEdit(parent)
        return line_edit

class DelegateLWidget(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        list_widget = QListWidget(parent)
        list_widget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        return list_widget
```

Everything seems to work fine except for one thing. Whenever I double click on any cell in the QListWidget column, the contents of that particular cell are set to -1. I have not handled the "doubleClicked" signal. Even when I did (I made it print the content of the cell on a textBrowser), double clicking the cell set the contents to -1. Can anyone please help me through this? I have tried reading the QTableWidget documentation but did not find any success. Can someone please point out what am I missing?
Here is the **init** function of my Form class

```
def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
    self.list_widget = QListWidget()
    self.add_button.clicked.connect(self.add_to_list)
    # self.table.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.print_cell_content)

    self.table.setColumnCount(2)

    first_header = "Option"
    second_header = "Directories"

    header = first_header + ";" + second_header
    self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(header.split(";"))
    header = self.table.horizontalHeader()

    header.setResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

    self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()
    # self.table.setShowGrid(False)

    self.delegate_lw = DelegateLWidget(self)
    self.delegate_le = DelegateLEdit(self)

    self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, self.delegate_le)
    self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, self.delegate_lw)
```

EDIT:
handler for add button that adds files to the second column of table

```
def add_to_list(self):

    file_dialog = QFileDialog(self)
    file_dialog.saveState()
    file_dialog.setOption(QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog, True)


    file_list = file_dialog.getOpenFileNames()
    self.dir_list.extend(file_list)
    self.dir_list = list(set(self.dir_list)) 
    self.add_items(self.dir_list)  

def add_items(self, list_items):
    list_items.sort()
    column = 1
    self.row_count = 0
    for item in list_items:
        self.table.insertRow(self.row_count)
        self.table.setItem(self.row_count, column, QTableWidgetItem(item))
        self.row_count += 1
```

Thank You

Comment: You could show how to add items to the table

Comment: You seem to be using the item-delegate to provide a custom editor, which is only visible when editing. Is that what you really want? Or do you actually want to set an item widget, which is visible at all times? What do you expect to happen when double-clicking in a cell?

Comment: @ekhumoro yeah, I actually want the widget to be visible when editing. The problem is with the second column where I am using item-delegate for the list-widget. When I am double clicking on any cell in that column, the value of that cell is reset to -1. i am hoping to avoid that

Comment: @eyllanesc I am sorry. Do you mean I should add the code for that here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement [setEditorData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemdelegate.html#setEditorData) and [setModelData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemdelegate.html#setModelData) in your delegate, in order to be able to store and retrieve the model's data. For the list-widget column, the default behaviour is to display the current index, which will be `-1` for an empty list.

Here is what your delegate classes should look like:

```
class DelegateLEdit(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        line_edit = QLineEdit(parent)
        return line_edit

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.setText(index.data())

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.text())

class DelegateLWidget(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        list_widget = QListWidget(parent)
        list_widget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        list_widget.addItems('One Two Three Four'.split()) # or whatever
        return list_widget

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        for line in index.data().splitlines():
            for item in editor.findItems(line, Qt.MatchExactly):
                item.setSelected(True)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        text = '\n'.join(item.text() for item in editor.selectedItems())
        model.setData(index, text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. This solved a big part of my problem. I slightly modified the code to adjust to my need but I am facing some other issue now. When I double click on the item in the list_widget, it disappears and then comes back if I click on any other item. Is that supposed to happen? The only modification that I made are:

Removed the `list_widget.addItems()` as it was done in the Form class

and changed line to
`line = index.data()`. In either case, editor.findItems() gives a list of len 0

Comment: @0Nicholas. If you removed `addItems`, how are you populating the list? Do you only want to select **one** item from the list? If so, a combo-box would be a much better choice of editor widget.

Comment: I have added a QPushButton which is connected to `add_to_list()` method. I have edited the question and added the code for the same. Is that a bad way of populating the list-widget?

Comment: @0Nicholas. Yes, it is a bad way, because it doesn't add anything to the list-widget used by the delegate for editing, so it will be empty. What do you want to appear in that list? And do you want to able to select only **one** item from that list, or **multiple** items? At the moment, I can't really understand why you are using those delegates at all, as you don't appear to be using them for editing.

Comment: I am adding paths of files and folders to the list. I am a newbie to PyQt. Using delegates seemed to be a good way to convert cells of one column of the table to QLineEdits and those of other columns to QLineWidget. You are right, I don't intend to use delegate for editing, but only for getting a "custom-table". Is there any other way I can do this? Have been scratching my head over this for days now.

Comment: @0Nicholas. Your requirements are still extremely unclear. And you haven't answered all the questions I asked in my previous comments. I cannot help you if you don't make a reasonable effort to explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I apologize. I will try to explain my motive behind the application. I want user to be able to select files and folder from the system. I used a two-column table. The first column is intended to hold a "key" to which the file/folder paths added to the second column are mapped. I want user to be able to enter and edit the "key" at his/her will. Hence I used a delegate to convert the first column of the table to QLineEdit.

Comment: The second column is where file/folder paths are to be added. I used a delegate to convert the second column into a QListWidget (it seemed easier to do this way). I am using an add button to select and add file/folder paths to the second column (QListWidget). The "add button" uses QFileDialog to enter the said paths to the QListWidget. Now, when the paths are added, double-clicking the path (which I assume is a common user behavior) sets the cell to -1. I don't want anything to happen on double-clicking a particular cell. Does this clear some of the stuff?

Comment: @0Nicholas. No, it doesn't. In your question, you are adding the file-paths to the **table**, rather than to a list-widget. Also, I have asked you several times to state whether **each cell** in the second column contains **one** file-path or **multiple** file-paths. If it only contains **one**, I cannot see why you would want to use a list-widget, because that would normally contain **multiple** items. Also, I don't understand why you would want to add line-edits to the first column, given that a table-widget uses line-edits for all its cells anyway.

Comment: Each cell in the second column contains only one file-path. I think I understand what you are trying to say. The default table would be a better choice, right?

Comment: no problem :) thank you. You have been a great help :D